# Checkboxes not displaying any browser

Tags: css, checkbox, browser

I don't understand what is problem in this code. In this code when I add hidden type tag then checkbox don't show other wise its work fine...

CSS Code

```
.example{
  margin-bottom : 1.5em;
}

input[type=checkbox]:not(old),
input[type=radio   ]:not(old){
  width     : 2em;
  margin    : 0;
  padding   : 0;
  font-size : 1em;
  opacity   : 0;
}

input[type=checkbox]:not(old) + label,
input[type=radio   ]:not(old) + label{
  display      : inline-block;
  margin-left  : -2em;
  line-height  : 1.5em;
}

input[type=checkbox]:not(old) + label > span,
input[type=radio   ]:not(old) + label > span{
  display          : inline-block;
  width            : 0.875em;
  height           : 0.875em;
  margin           : 0.25em 0.5em 0.25em 0.25em;
  border           : 0.0625em solid rgb(192,192,192);
  border-radius    : 0.25em;
  background       : rgb(224,224,224);
  background-image :    -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  background-image :     -ms-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  background-image :      -o-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  background-image : -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  background-image :         linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  vertical-align   : bottom;
}

input[type=checkbox]:not(old):checked + label > span,
input[type=radio   ]:not(old):checked + label > span{
  background-image :    -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
  background-image :     -ms-linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
  background-image :      -o-linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
  background-image : -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
  background-image :         linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
}

input[type=checkbox]:not(old):checked + label > span:before{
/*   content     : '✓'; */
  content       : "\221A";
  display     : block;
  width       : 1em;
  color       : rgb(153,204,102);
  font-size   : 0.875em;
  line-height : 1em;
  text-align  : center;
  text-shadow : 0 0 0.0714em rgb(115,153,77);
  font-weight : bold;
}

input[type=radio]:not(old):checked +  label > span > span{
  display          : block;
  width            : 0.5em;
  height           : 0.5em;
  margin           : 0.125em;
  border           : 0.0625em solid rgb(115,153,77);
  border-radius    : 0.125em;
  background       : rgb(153,204,102);
  background-image :    -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
  background-image :     -ms-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
  background-image :      -o-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
  background-image : -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
  background-image :         linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
}
```

HTML Code:

```html
<div class="panel-body">
  <table class="table">
    <s:iterator value="eligibilityList" status="status">
      <s:if test='%{lkpGroupId == "160100000005"}'>
        <tr>
          <td style="visibility: hidden;"><s:property value='lkpDataId' />
          </td>
          <td><s:property value='lkpDataName' />
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="example">
              <div>
                <s:if test='%{chackBoxStatus == "1"}'>
                  <input id="<s:property value='lkpDataId' />" class="chackBoxIdPrefix" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked="checked">
                  <input value="1" id="hid_<s:property value='lkpDataId' />" type="hidden" name="checkbox1" />
                </s:if>
                <s:else>
                  <input id="<s:property value='lkpDataId' />" class="chackBoxIdPrefix" type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
                  <input value="0" id="hid_<s:property value='lkpDataId' />" type="hidden" name="checkbox1" />
                </s:else>
                <label for="checkbox2"><span></span>bind For Prefix</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </s:if>
    </s:iterator>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" align="center">
        <input type="button" value="Save Change" class="btn-info" align="middle">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: the whole point of `type="hidden"` is to *not show* a form element.

Comment: now what is the solution ?

Comment: don't put `input="hidden"` unless you actually want to *hide* the checkbox. or maybe I just vastly misunderstand the question.

Comment: But in my business i need hidden type tag for checked and unchecked value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the `input type=hidden` is between the checkbox and label and the styles width this kind of selectors **checkbox + label** are not applied.

Comment: also applied with out label  but same result

Comment: I mean that maybe you should place `input type=hidden` elsewhere, before checkbox, for example.

Comment: `input hidden` after checkbox: https://jsfiddle.net/blonfu/5h4u633d/       

`input hidden` before checkbox: https://jsfiddle.net/blonfu/o4ybygwf/